# Python's "pop" equivalent in Mathematica

Tags: functions, python

I will like to know if there is an equivalent to python's pop method, here is how it's done in Python:

```python
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> value = my_list.pop(0)
>>> value
1
>>> my_list
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

With pop you get and delete an element from a list.

Comment: Try the commands First (to get the first element) and Rest (to get the remainder of the elements)

Comment: @bills and if I want to do pop(4)? The idea is right but i want to be able to grab any element on the list.

Comment: Then use Part: list[[1;;4]] and list[[5;;All]]

Comment: Why are you looking for an equivalent?  In Mathematica it is generally not a good idea to mutate data structures.  There is no equivalent because such a function (that both modifies its argument and returns something) really has no place in a language like Mathematica.  Are you looking for an efficient stack data structure?  If so, consider a nested list like `{3, {2, {1, {}}}}`. Use `First` and `Rest` to pop an item from it.

Comment: pop is like Part[ ] but with an additional side effect. In Mathematica we normally try to avoid side effects. However we have functions like AppendTo that work like that.

Comment: That should be First and Last, not First and Rest,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. You could use something like this:

```
SetAttributes[pop, HoldFirst]
pop[list_, n_] := With[{item = list[[n]]}, list = Delete[list, n]; item]

mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

pop[mylist, 4]
(* 4 *)

mylist
(* {1, 2, 3, 5} *)
```

Comment: See @JoseLuisMartin 's answer.  Surprisingly there *is* an equivalent.

Comment: @QuantumDot I wouldn't say that's equivalent - pop alters the list whereas TakeDrop returns a new list.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed.

Answer (score 9):

TakeDrop[list,seq]

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6};
seq  = {2, 3};
pair = TakeDrop[list, seq] (* {{2, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 6}} *)
list = pair[[2]]           (* {1, 4, 5, 6} *)
pop = pair[[1]]            (* {2,2} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way that I think mimics the Python script well.

```
myList = Range[5];
{value, myList} = {#, {##2}} & @@ myList;
Column[{value, myList}]
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Introduced in v10, you can use `Nothing`:

```
mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

(* save the particular item, if you need it *)
item = mylist[[1]];

mylist[[1]] = Nothing;
(* mylist = {2, 3, 4, 5} *)

mylist == {2, 3, 4, 5}
(* True *)

mylist === {2, 3, 4, 5}
(* True *)
```

More info [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html).